# what is the fault in my gradient descent algorithm built manually?

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am a learner of data science and machine learning. I have written a code for gradient descent optimization of linear regression cost function without using builtin python library. However, just to confirm whether my code is correct and verify results, I have also implemented the same using builtin python library. 
The coefficient and intercept values I obtained through my code are not matching with the coefficient and intercept values obtained using builtin python module. Kindly suggest what is the error in my way of gradient descent optimization of linear regression?

my method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor

Data=pd.DataFrame({'X': list(np.arange(0,10,1)), 'Y': [1,3,2,5,7,8,8,9,10,12]})
Data.head()

sb.scatterplot(x ='X', y = 'Y', data = Data)
plt.show()

#generating column of ones
X0 = np.ones(len(Data)).reshape(-1,1)
#print(X0.shape)

X = Data.drop(['Y'], axis = 1).values
X_new = np.concatenate((X0,X), axis = 1)
#print(X_new)
#print(X_new.shape)

Y = Data.loc[:,['Y']].values
#print(Y)
#print(Y.shape)

# initial theta
theta =np.random.randint(low=0, high=1, size= X_new.shape[1]).reshape(-1,1)
#print(theta.shape)

J_history = []
theta_history = [list(theta.flatten())]

#gradient descent implementation
iterations = 1000
alpha = 0.01
m = len(Y)
for iter in range(1,iterations):
    H = X_new.dot(theta)
    loss = (H-Y)
    J = loss/(2*m)
    J_history.append(J)
    G = X_new.T.dot(loss)/m
    theta_new = theta - alpha*G    
    theta_history.append(list(theta_new.flatten()))
    theta = theta_new

# collecting costs (J) and coefficients (theta_0,theta_1)

theta_history.pop()
J_history = [i[0] for i in J_history]

params = pd.DataFrame()
params['J']=J_history

for i in range(len(theta_history[0])):
    params['theta_'+str(i)]=[k[i] for k in theta_history]

idx = params[params['J']==min(params['J'])].index
values = params.iloc[idx[0]][1:params.shape[1]].tolist()
print('intercept: {}, coeff: {}'.format(values[0],values[1]))
```

using builtin library:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor

Data=pd.DataFrame({'X': list(np.arange(0,10,1)), 'Y': [1,3,2,5,7,8,8,9,10,12]})
Data.head()

sb.scatterplot(x ='X', y = 'Y', data = Data)
plt.show()
model = SGDRegressor(loss = 'squared_loss', learning_rate = 'constant', eta0 = 0.01, max_iter= 1000)
model.fit(Data['X'].values.reshape(-1,1), Data['Y'].values.reshape(-1,1))
print('coeff: {}, intercept: {}'.format(model.coef_, model.intercept_))
```

Comment: Are you sure of your code? this line `idx = params[params['J']==min(params['J'])].index
` raises `ValueError: Lengths must match to compare` when I run it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I appreciate your effort to understand and implement by yourself the SGD algorithm.

Now, back to your code. There are some minor errors that need to be corrected:

- Your `J`s are not scalars but `numpy.array`s but the way you're using them implies that they're assumed to be scalars hence the error raised when your code is executed.
- After running your chain, you must take the **theta** who has the lowest error and this error is actually **J^2** and not **J** as **J** may be negative as well.
- The scikit learn **SGDRegressor** that you're actually using is, as its name suggests, stochastic by definition and given the small size of your dataset you need to run it many times and average its estimates if you want to get something reliable from it.
- Your learning rate **0.01** seems to be a little big

When those changes are made, I get from your code a "comparable" results with **SGDRegressor**.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor

Data=pd.DataFrame({'X': list(np.arange(0,10,1)), 'Y': [1,3,2,5,7,8,8,9,10,12]})
Data.head()

sb.scatterplot(x ='X', y = 'Y', data = Data)
plt.show()


#generating column of ones
X0 = np.ones(len(Data)).reshape(-1,1)
#print(X0.shape)

X = Data.drop(['Y'], axis = 1).values
X_new = np.concatenate((X0,X), axis = 1)
#print(X_new)
#print(X_new.shape)

Y = Data.loc[:,['Y']].values
#print(Y)
#print(Y.shape)

# initial theta
theta =np.random.randint(low=0, high=1, size= X_new.shape[1]).reshape(-1,1)
#print(theta.shape)

J_history = []
theta_history = [list(theta.flatten())]

#gradient descent implementation
iterations = 2000
alpha = 0.001
m = len(Y)
for iter in range(1,iterations):
    H = X_new.dot(theta)
    loss = (H-Y)
    J = loss/(2*m)
    J_history.append(J[0]**2)
    G = X_new.T.dot(loss)/m
    theta_new = theta - alpha*G    
    theta_history.append(list(theta_new.flatten()))
    theta = theta_new
theta_history.pop()
J_history = [i[0] for i in J_history]


# collecting costs (J) and coefficients (theta_0,theta_1)

params = pd.DataFrame()
params['J']=J_history

for i in range(len(theta_history[0])):
    params['theta_'+str(i)]=[k[i] for k in theta_history]

idx = params[params['J']== params['J'].min()].index
values = params.iloc[idx[0]][1:params.shape[1]].tolist()
print('intercept: {}, coeff: {}'.format(values[0],values[1]))

#> intercept: 0.654041555750147, coeff: 1.2625626277290982
```

## Now let's see the scikit learn model

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor

intercepts = []
coefs = []
for _ in range(500):
    model = SGDRegressor(loss = 'squared_loss', learning_rate = 'constant',  eta0 = 0.01, max_iter= 1000)
    model.fit(Data['X'].values.reshape(-1,1), Data['Y'].values.reshape(-1))
    intercepts.append(model.intercept_)
    coefs.append(model.coef_)
intercept = np.concatenate(intercepts).mean()
coef = np.vstack(coefs).mean(0)
print('intercept: {}, coeff: {}'.format( intercept, coef))
#> intercept: 0.6912403374422401, coeff: [1.24932246]
```